# Javascript Issue with function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is returning an "Unexpected Token New" error at line 3. I am not sure why this is happening. It seems correct to me.

```
function flat_array(array){

 var new = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
      new = new.concat(array[i]);
  }

  return new;
}
```

Comment: new is  a reserved keyword.. change the variable name and it will work..

Comment: Sidenote: `Array.flat()` and `Array.flatMap()` are being implemented in modern browsers, so depending on which browsers you support, you might want to use the native `.flat()` method.

Answer (score 2):

`new` is a reserved word for constructing objects (note the highlighting here even):

```
obj = new Object()
```

It can't be used as a name for variables. Change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

you can't name a variable called `new` as the word is reserved (like in most programming languages)

I'd suggest calling your variable "newObj" or something like that if you really want the "new" part, but you can't call a variable with a reserved word. Here's a [list of keywords in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Answer (score 0):

new is a reserved word. You cannot use it as a name of a variable. 
Changing your code to below should work fine:

```
function flat_array(arr){
  var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      result = result.concat(arr[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` is the reserved word in JS. You can't use it as a variable name. Here is the list of the JS reserved words:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

You can find what's the purpose of `new` here:
[What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)